# .dll, .winmd can be read in Unity but not in XAML project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, hololens

I have a c++ `.dll` and `.winmd` from [this solution](https://github.com/doughtmw/HoloLensForCV/tree/4778ed937de6f09a57e7672e0e1cef034d8271e5). When I put them in a Plugin folder in Unity, build the Universal Windows project and deploy to the Hololens 2, the classes in the `.dll` and `.winmd` are recognized.

If I create a Visual Studio Universal Windows XAML project, copy the `.dll` and `.winmd` to the project path and include the `.winmd` via Reference-Add, all the classes are there during editing (no errors thrown during editing and building). When I build the solution, the `.dll` is also copied to the build path. If I, however, deploy and run the code, the project throws the following exception:

```
 'ResearchMode.exe' (Win32): Unloaded U:\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\78ac9912-63f6-43a8-b469-6e4684f8ea08VS.Release_ARM.cwule\HoloLensForCV.dll
onecore\com\combase\objact\dllcache.cxx(2132)\combase.dll!7728B3FD: (caller: 771AC799) ReturnHr(1) tid(178) 8007007E The specified module could not be found.
onecore\com\combase\objact\dllcache.cxx(4634)\combase.dll!771AC7B3: (caller: 771AB0A9) ReturnHr(2) tid(178) 8007007E The specified module could not be found.
onecore\com\combase\objact\dllcache.cxx(4766)\combase.dll!771AC7CB: (caller: 771AB0A9) ReturnHr(3) tid(178) 8007007E The specified module could not be found.
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in System.Private.Interop.dll
The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

Am I including the `.winmd` and `.dll` incorrectly? What could be the reason why they are loaded correctly for the Unity project but not for the XAML project? Anything else I need to specify for these assemblies that Unity perhaps already does for me that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. The project above delivered a `HoloLensForCV.winmd` and a `HoloLensForCV.dll` and a `opencv_world3411.dll`. In addition to adding `HoloLensForCV.winmd` via Reference-Add (which copied `HoloLensForCV.dll` to the output directory), I needed to manually add `opencv_world3411.dll` to the solution via Add-Existing item (chose "Copy always").